# Accessing a Tab Control From Second Form And Inserting The Form Into First Form Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

Please, I am having a slight issue working with tabControl. I have a tabControl which is on a first form. Initially, I had issues trying to access the tabControl from another form. But I later found a way out by changing the control accessibility in the designer from private to public.
However, when I try to show the from inside the tab, it doesn’t work. But from the first form, I am able to easily put other forms inside the tabpage since I have the control there. From from another form, I am having difficulties.

Here is a code trying to search data from the db

```
patient selectUser = new patient();
        //Get Selected Patient based on end user click from the DataGridView
        public patient GetSelectedUser()
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
            {
                selectUser.patient_id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["patient_id"].Value);

                using (DbModel db = new DbModel ())
                {
                    selectUser = db.patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.patient_id == selectUser.patient_id);
                }
            }
            return selectUser;
        }
```

Here is the code trying to include the form inside a tabcontrol.

```
StartPage sp = new StartPage();

    private void LoadSelectedUser()
    {
        patient patient = GetSelectedUser();
        if (patient == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("cannot load data");
        }
        else
        {

            //Close();
            //StartPage.tt = "";
            //PatientDashboard pd = new PatientDashboard(patient);
            //pd.Show();


            Close();
            PatientDashboard pd = new PatientDashboard(patient);

            TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
            tabpage.Text = pd.Text;
            sp.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage);
            pd.TopLevel = false;
            pd.Parent = tabpage;
            pd.Show();
            pd.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            sp.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabpage;
            pd.Show();

        }
    }
```

I notice that the TopLevel Property of a form makes the form not to show.
Will sincerely appreciate any assistance as i have been on this for 2days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
tabpage.Controls.Add(pd)
```

**Update:**

program.cs

```
public static Form1 from;  //<--- important
/// <summary>
/// The main entry point for the application.
/// </summary>
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       using (Form1 mainForm = new Form1())
       {
           from = mainForm;

           Application.Run(from);
       }
}
```

3rd form window or whatever:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();

    TabPage tabpage = new TabPage();
    tabpage.Text = f2.Text;
    Program.from.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabpage);
    f2.TopLevel = false;
    f2.Parent = tabpage;
    f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Program.from.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabpage;
    f2.Show();
}
```

That should help you manipulate things for the main form.

Comment: @Godymn Sorry I just realized you were manipulating main form from another form. You need to expose a static form so you can manipulate across forms.

Comment: your the main boss!. Thanks alot. This worked like a charm!!!. Thank you once again, i appreciate.